# SQL1024N when using DB2 in Cygwin

Tags: db2, cygwin

I have DB2 version 11.1.0.1527 on Windows 10
and Cygwin version 3.2.0(0.340/5/3)

I am trying to use DB2 from within Cygwin but it is not holding onto the db2 connection after successfully connecting.

Anyone have any suggestions?

How to reproduce:

**(1)** Start a Windows cmd window as Administrator

**(2)** Start a "DB2 Command Window - Administrator" :

"C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\BIN\db2cwadmin.bat"

**(3)** Start Cygwin inside the DB2 Command Window :

C:\cygwin64\bin\mintty.exe -i /Cygwin-Terminal.ico -

**(4)** Manually connect to the database(successfully) :

GMX+I10030754@DESKTOP-I1IQG9H ~

$ db2 connect to DB3270GA user db2admin using password

Database Connection Information

Database server        = DB2/NT64 11.1.0

SQL authorization ID   = DB2ADMIN

Local database alias   = DB3270GA

**(5)** Running any sql statement returns SQL1024N

GMX+I10030754@DESKTOP-I1IQG9H ~

$ db2 select * from myschema.application

**SQL1024N**  A database connection does not exist.  SQLSTATE=08003

Comment: in your bash (or whichever shell you are using) startup file, is the DB2CLP environment variable exported?  Example: `export DB2CLP=**$$** `  ?

Comment: @mao Thanks for that suggestion. When I added that export - it then failed to connect to DB2 at step(4) with DB21018E. I replaced that export statement with "export DB2CLP=DB20FADE" as recommended elsewhere and the original issue returned - failed at step (5) with SQL1024N.

Comment: after exporting the variable, kill any previously existing db2bp.exe started from cygwin.  Ensure to exit from and restart bash, then retry. It is the `db2bp.exe` that keeps the database-connection, so that process needs to continue to exist and have communications from db2.exe (clp) when it runs.  If db2.exe cannot contact or identify the db2bp.exe background task you get the SQL1024N I believe.

Comment: @mao That appears to be the issue. I can see a db2dp.exe process start up in the Task Manager when i issue the DB2 connect command. However it disappears after a few seconds. The question now is : how can we keep that background task(db2dp.exe) alive?

Comment: Does the same symptom if you use ksh (pdksh) instead of bash as the shell (still need to export the DB2CLP variable in the .profile or .kshrc for shell). ?

Answer (score 1):

Try the following in a cygwin session:

```
export DB2CLP=**$$**
# a connection will be closed after 5 seconds of inactivity otherwise
export DB2RQTIME=3600
db2 connect ...
sleep 10
db2 "select ..."
```

Comment: @mao and Mark, thank you both very much for spending time on this. I have tried various exports as suggested(and others) but the problem remains the same. Due to time pressures, I have to abandon this Cygwin approach.

Comment: The commands in this answer worked for me with Cygwin 3.4.6 and Db2 v11.5.8000.317 on Windows 10 v22H2. It also appears that Cygwin is the only command shell on Windows that needs the DB2CLP environment variable set to the pid of the current shell via `export DB2CLP=**$$**` in order for the Db2 CLP to work properly. The Db2 CLP evidently works fine in CMD.EXE and PowerShell no matter what value is assigned to DB2CLP, so long as it contains something.

Comment: It may help to point out that I needed to save the above commands into my `~/.bash_profile`

Answer (score 0):

Older versions of Cygwin (e.g. 1.7.3) expand $$ to the Windows PID, newer versions (e.g. 3.3.4) to the Cygwin PID.
So you have to use:
export DB2CLP="**$(cat /proc/$$/winpid)**"
...and everything works fine.